# Can't scan with Kodak ESP-5210 in gscan2pdf

Tags: 17.10, scanner, sane, kodak

I upgraded to 17.10 last month or so and since then scanning with `gscan2pdf` has not worked.

It did work under 17.04 and 16.04 though. Funny thing is, my scanner appears under `scanimage -L` and actually scans using `scanimage > /tmp/test.png`. `gscan2pdf`, however, gives me "Error retrieving scanner options: error getting option 6: Invalid argument". I tried under `xsane` and that's giving me the same problem.